# How do you explicitly create a copy of a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, reference

I have an array of stdClass objects. When I assign one to a variable, it is not copying the variable but instead referencing the original variable. My code is like this:

```
for ( $i = 0, $len = count($rows); $i < $len; $i++ )
{
    $row = $rows[$i];
    echo $rows[$i]->games;
    $row->games = 'test';
    echo $rows[$i]->games;
}
```

The first echo outputs the normal value, but the second echo outputs "test". Even though I am setting the property on `$row` (which should be copied), it's actually setting it on the original array element.

Why is this, and how do I actually create a copy, so that modifying the copy doesn't modify the original?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use the [`clone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) keyword.

```
$copy = clone $object;
```

important to note:

> When an object is cloned, PHP 5 will perform a shallow copy of all of the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other variables, will remain references.

it comes with a nice magic method:

> Once the cloning is complete, if a __clone() method is defined, then the newly created object's __clone() method will be called, to allow any necessary properties that need to be changed.